# Exception in logging module itself is not sent to sentry

Tags: python, django, logging, sentry

Django app on python 2 (yeah I know). The sentry integration is working well otherwise, but looks like it doesn't record crashes in logging itself, for instance when passing insufficient arguments to logger.info().

In this case the incriminating line was something like:

```
logger.info('some info about %s and %s', my_thing)
```

i.e. missing an argument.

This traceback showed up in heroku logs but nothing in sentry:

```
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9 Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 868, in emit
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9     msg = self.format(record)
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 741, in format
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9     return fmt.format(record)
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 465, in format
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9     record.message = record.getMessage()
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 329, in getMessage
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9     msg = msg % self.args
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9 TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
Apr 27 23:35:32 xxx app/web.9 Logged from file models.py, line 18407
```

Do I need to do something for sentry_sdk to include whatever context the logging module is running in as well?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to create a wrapper function for logging which explicitly captures exceptions

```
def log_info(*args):
  try:
    logger.info(*args)
  except Exception as e:
    sentry_sdk.capture_exception(e)
```

Drawback is that you'll need to change logging everywhere in your project.